# Java - SSL - Authenticating with gmail's SMTP server

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, smtp, gmail

I am able to connect to smtp.gmail.com via port 465. After using the AUTH LOGIN command receive a 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 which when decoded is "Username:"

I can't seem to figure out how to send my username over the server. I am encoding the username and sending, but getting no reply. The next reply should be to ask for my Password.

See below:

```
public class MailComponent{
Socket socket = null;
final static String MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com";
final static int SMTP_PORT = 465;
String uName = "example@gmail.com";
String encodedName = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(uName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

public MailComponent(){ /*Create constructor later*/}

public void sendMail() throws Exception{

    try{
        // Establish TCP Connection With Mail Server
        socket = ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(MAIL_SERVER, SMTP_PORT);

        // Create a Buffered Reader to read one line at a time
        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

        // Read Server's Greeting
        String serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Greeting: " + serverResponse);           
        if (!serverResponse.startsWith("220")){
            throw new Exception("220 Reply Not Received From Server!");
        }

        // Reference socket's output stream
        OutputStream oStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        // Send HELO command
        String heloCommand = "HELO smtp.gmail.com\r\n";
        oStream.write(heloCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("HELO Response: " + serverResponse);
        if (!serverResponse.startsWith("250"))
            throw new Exception("250 Reply Not Received From Server!");

        // Obtain Authorization
        String authCommand = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
        oStream.write(authCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Auth Response: " + serverResponse);

        // Give Username
        oStream.write(encodedName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));    
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Username Response: " + serverResponse);
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I don't receive any reply once I send my username. Any ideas on why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once asked for the username, you must send it encoded as well as sending the CR/LF as Dmitry Streblechenko added in his last comment. However, If you send a username along with the CL/LF the server will think it is part of the username or password and continue waiting for client response. I got it to work by simply sending both in separate messages.

As a note: The STARTTLS command wasn't necessary as I am using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You must use TLS on port 587 when connecting to the outlook.com or Office 365 SMTP servers - they will not accept the connection otherwise.

Comment: I have tried using port 587 as well. I get the same Issue. I am not sure what the actual Authorization command should be. Right now i'm trying "AUTH LOGIN\r\n" and I get the same reply. Do you know what the auth command should be?

Comment: 587 and you need to switch to TSL before authenticating since they won't allow the credentials to be sent over an unencrypted connection.

Comment: I used STARTTLS and got a message back from the server saying TLS is started, but I can't do anything from there. Anything command I send after that yields no response (good or bad). 

Could you please show me an example of what commands to use? I've been at this for days and have been looking for a solution.

Comment: You need to use encryption (SSL) to talk to the server. No more plain text data after STARTTLS. You really need to use a library to do that.

Comment: I am using SSLSocketFactory to make a socket connection to gmail's smtp port 465 and get a server request for my username, but I can't figure out how to send it. I tried to encode my username but i'm not getting a reply.

Comment: You need to issue the STARTTLS command, make sure you get back 220, and only then switch to the encrypted connection. You REALLY need to use an SMTP library that supports TLS natively. Don't try to do it on your own unless you really want to learns all the ins and outs of the protocol.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. I get a response from HELO, then if i try to use STARTTLS afterwards I receive 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Meaning that I have to send my username and password. If I had to use the STARTTLS command it would have said that in response.

Comment: And again, once i send AUTH LOGIN the server replies that it is requesting my username.

Comment: The actual SSL connection should start *after* you receive the 220 response to STARTTLS. When do you initiate the SSL connection?

Comment: The SSL connection is started from the get-go. I see what you're saying. I'll have to try to create a socket to connect/say helo/ start TLS, THEn move on to creating a SSL socket connection.

Comment: I never tried to do TLS that way. Only after sending the starttls command.

Comment: Any idea on the syntax of the username and password?

Comment: Send 'AUTH LOGIN + CR/LF, make sure you get back 334, send base 64 encoded user name + CR/LF, make sure you get back 334, send base 64 encoded password + CR/LF, make sure you get back 235.